# Msgbox VBA on closed workbook

Tags: vba, search, path, folder-redirection

I have 2 different workbooks:

- workbook-1
- workbook-2

I want msgbox in workbook-1 referring to values in workbook-2.

For example:

In workbook-1:

```
| A |
| B |
| C |
```

In workbook-2:

```
| A | 10 | 5  | 6 | 4 |

| B | 5  | 4  | 2 | 1 |

| C | 5  | 10 | 5 | 6 |
```

When I give key (A) on workbook-1, it should refer to the values in workbook-2 and show as a msgbox.

Msg box:

```
| A  |
| 10 |
| 5  |
| 6  |
| 4  |
```

The code I have so far is:

```
Sub Search()
```

Msg = "CALL DETAILS" & vbCr

dim path as String

dim file as String

dim sheet as String

path = "C:\Users\naresh.g\Desktop\vlookup\"

file = "workbook2.xlsx"

sheet = "sheet2"

```
  If (path & file & sheet) <> "" Then
```

'i am getting error here as subscript out of range error code 9

'sometime i am getting object require

```
    For Each cell In Sheets("sheet2").Range("B2:B" & Sheets("sheet2").Cells(Rows.Count, "B").End(xlUp).Row)
        If LCase(cell.Value) = LCase(Selection.Value) Or InStr(1, LCase(cell.Value), _
            LCase(Selection.Value)) > 0 Then
                Msg = Msg & vbCr & cell.Offset(0, 1) & " / " & vbCr & cell.Offset(0, 2) & " / " & cell.Value
        End If
    Next 
    i = MsgBox(Msg, vbInformation)
End Sub
```

Comment: What exactly is your problem/question?

Comment: Hi, i want to pick the matching values from closed workbook.

Comment: Above mentioned code is working on the same workbook , but when i give direction and path it shows error.

Comment: Please [edit] your question to include the error.

Comment: Hi! Question edited